# How do I access hash value in webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

**Accessing hash value in webpack.config.js**

```
//Sample webpack.config.js File  

var webpack = require('webpack');

console.log("[hash]");//How to access hash value??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `hash` through `stats`. Demo:

```
webpack({
    ...
}, function(err, stats) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    console.log(stats.hash);
});
```